# How do I turn on the blinking cursor in Terminal on Mac?

Tags: xcode, macos, terminal, view

I've got Terminal open, but the cursor doesn't blink. I would like it to blink for my own aesthetic appeals. I looked under *View* but didn't see an option to enable blinking cursor.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wX6YS.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong site - try [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/). But you can find the option under Preferences -> Profiles -> Blink Cursor.

[image: Preferences -> Profiles -> Blink Cursor]